# VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: could not create new file : box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Can any one help me into this error!!!

Following are the versions installed on my machines:

- Vagrant 2.2.0
- VirtualBox: 5.0.16r105871
- Gem: 2.7.5
- Chef Development Kit Version: 2.0.28

  ```
  PS C:\nginx\html\cereved\dev-environment> vagrant up
  ==> frontend: Box 'mvbcoding/awslinux' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
      frontend: Box Provider: virtualbox
      frontend: Box Version: >= 0
  ==> frontend: Loading metadata for box 'mvbcoding/awslinux'
      frontend: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/mvbcoding/awslinux
  ==> frontend: Adding box 'mvbcoding/awslinux' (v2017.03.0.20170401) for provider: virtualbox
      frontend: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/mvbcoding/boxes/awslinux/versions/2017.03.0.20170401/providers/virtualbox.box
      frontend: Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
      frontend:
  ==> frontend: Successfully added box 'mvbcoding/awslinux' (v2017.03.0.20170401) for 'virtualbox'!
      frontend: The Berkshelf shelf is at "C:/Users/*******/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20190103-12584-svd029-frontend"
  ==> frontend: Sharing cookbooks with VM
  ==> frontend: Importing base box 'mvbcoding/awslinux'...
  Progress: 90%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
  for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

  Command: ["import", "\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\*******\\.vagrant.d\\boxes\\mvbcoding-VAGRANTSLASH-awslinux\\2017.03.0.20170401\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "amzn-ami-hvm-2017030201
  70401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546506401977_30636", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "7", "--disk", "C:\\Users\\*******\\VirtualBox VMs\\amzn-ami-hvm-201
  703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546506401977_30636\\box-disk001.vmdk"]

  Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
  Interpreting \\?\C:\Users\*******\.vagrant.d\boxes\mvbcoding-VAGRANTSLASH-awslinux\2017.03.0.20170401\virtualbox\box.ovf...
  OK.
  0%...
  Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670
  _1546506401977_30636\box-disk001.vmdk'.
  VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: could not create new file 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546
  506401977_30636/box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 877 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
  ```

  I reinstalled the Oracle VirtualBox and Vagrant software's. 
  I tried to run the "vagrant up" command after deleting the ".vagrant.d" and "VirtualBox VMs", but the problem still exists.

I am not sure from where its throwing error. Any suggestion will be helpful!!!

Also, I am attaching the log of VirtualBox

```
00:00:00.616136          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={Could not find a registered machine named 'amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:00.617136          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Could not find file for the medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670\box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:00.716925          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={Could not find a registered machine named 'amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:00.717926          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Could not find file for the medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670\box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:23.975604 ApplImp  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd} aComponent={MachineWrap} aText={Could not create the settings file 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227.vbox' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:23.976605 ApplImp  ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227\box-disk001.vmdk' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:25.142254          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={Could not find a registered machine named 'amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:25.144256          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Could not find file for the medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670\box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:25.161267 Medium::Task ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227\box-disk001.vmdk'.
00:00:25.161267 Medium::Task VMDK: could not create new file 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227/box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:25.162269 ApplImp  ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e} aComponent={ApplianceWrap} aText={Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227\box-disk001.vmdk'.
00:00:25.162269 ApplImp  VMDK: could not create new file 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227/box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:26.324906          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={Could not find a registered machine named 'amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:26.325907          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Could not find file for the medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670\box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:26.340679 Medium::Task ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227\box-disk001.vmdk'.
00:00:26.340679 Medium::Task VMDK: could not create new file 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227/box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:26.341179 ApplImp  ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e} aComponent={ApplianceWrap} aText={Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227\box-disk001.vmdk'.
00:00:26.341179 ApplImp  VMDK: could not create new file 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\amzn-ami-hvm-201703020170401-x86_64-gp2-201704051103-guest-72463CQOefdxv_default_1491390639577_72670_1546520279927_40227/box-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:31.353526 Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
```

Is Intel Virtualization Technology should be enabled in BIOS for this?
[image]

Comment: Is Intel Virtualization Technology should be enabled in BIOS for this?

Answer (score 2):

I also started getting a similar error the same time this question was opened.

I have found a temporary workaround:

1. Do a `vagrant up` , which will stop with the `VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS` error
2. Navigate to your VirtualBox VMs directory, which should have two subfolders - the base box folder and your target machines folder. In my case these were `company-base_default_1546511806177_12809` and `my-dev-vm` respectively.
3. Move the large `.vmdk` disk image file from the target folder back to the base box folder, which should still have the `.vbox` and `.vbox-prev` files inside.
4. In the VirtualBox GUI open the settings for the base box VM and change the name to that of your target VM.
5. Run `vagrant up` again.

I think this must be caused by a Vagrant incompatibility with VirtualBox 6, or a problem with the rename API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, in my case there is only one folder in VirtualBox VMs directory. I have attached the VirtualBox logs too. If you can check and help me out with that!!

Answer (score 2):

For my side (MacOS), I get this issue consistently if I keep opened in virtualbox 6.1.12 the machine settings while running the vagrant destroy and deleting the disk file.

To solve it in 2 steps per [this page](https://coderwall.com/p/8m--dq/purge-deleted-hard-disks-from-virtual-box) :

1. Get the UUID of the deleted disk

```
vboxmanage list hdds
```

2. Purge the deleted disk :

```
vboxmanage closemedium disk <uuid> --delete
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing below my Vagrantfile (working one), in case it can be a help! Have fun!
###############

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  (6..8).each do |i|
       config.vm.define "node#{i}" do |node|
       node.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
#      config.vm.define "ansible"
#      config.vm.provision "ansible", playbook: "ubuntu.yml"
       node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.3.#{i}", auto_config: true
#      config.vm.hostname = "node#{i}"
       node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
          # Do not load the command line GUI
          vb.gui = false
       file_to_disk = "node#{i}.vdi"
       unless File.exist?"node#{i}.vdi"
       vb.customize ['createhd', '--filename', file_to_disk, '--size', 20 * 1024]
  end

       # Virtual Machine Name
       vb.name = "node#{i}"
       vb.memory = "2512"
       vb.cpus = "2"
       # Network settings
       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
#
       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uart1", "0x3F8", 4]
       vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SCSI', '--port', 2, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', "node#{i}.vdi"]
#
#
      end
       node.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo hello from node #{i}"
#
       end
  end
  
end
```